# how do i install minimodem on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, configuration, installation

I've tried configuring minimodem package but the packages listed below couldn't be found...
`No package 'fftw3f' found
No package 'alsa' found
No package 'libpulse-simple' found
No package 'sndfile' found`

I've tried installing fftw3f based the walkthrough here [how to install fftw3f on mac](http://www.fftw.org/install/mac.html) and everything went fine but I still get the output that I've got earlier
how can I tell the configuration file that I've installed fftw3f package or how can I tell if I didn't installed it correctly ?
BTW minimodem can be found here [Minimodem Homepage](http://www.whence.com/minimodem/)

**UPDATE:**
I've installed minimodem with Paul R's solution 
The package available in brew is 0.19 , I've still looking forward to make 0.21 version and while configuring it the ffftw3f package dependency is still a problem which is not included in brew packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the better package managers, e.g. [homebrew](https://brew.sh) - it takes care of the dependencies and platform-specific stuff and generally makes life a lot easier:

```
$ brew install minimodem
```

Comment: the package available in brew is 0.19 , I've still looking forward to make 0.21 version and while configuring it the ffftw3f package is a problem which is not included in brew packages

Comment: Well once you have 0.19 installed and working the dependencies will be taken care of, so subsequently doing a manual install of 0.21 should then be much easier. Or you could even see if you can update the brew formula for 0.21.

Comment: I've tried the manual installation and it failed , will try the the brew formula update...tnx btw